# How do you fix the missing 'javadoc' command issue when calling maven from IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, javadoc

I keep getting this when calling `maven install` from IntelliJ:

```
Error while creating archive: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set.
```

I can run maven-install just fine from the terminal inside of my working directory, but does anyone know how to get this to actually work in IntelliJ?

Comment: What IDE version and what OS do you use? With IDEA 12 and older on Mac you may need to define `JAVA_HOME` environment variable per [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51677). IDEA 13 should read the Terminal environment automatically, but not from `.bash_profile`.

Comment: OSX IDEA12. Yeah, you're right, IDEA13 (CE, at least, I haven't upgraded my license yet) works just fine by actually loading the term environment. I guess I might start using it instead.

Comment: Great, I've posted it as an answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: I can confirm that trhis is not a Mac specific problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With IDEA 12 and older on Mac you may need to define `JAVA_HOME` environment variable [per this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51677). IDEA 13 should read the Terminal environment automatically, but not from `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Thanks. I've put up a gist of this for anyone who comes up to this on google and just wants things to copy/paste: https://gist.github.com/kimagure/7992583

edit: If only I could actually upvote...

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ check that the JRE for Maven is selected correctly to a JDK.

IntelliJ -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner

[image: Maven Runner JRE config]

The JRE-field needs to specify a **JDK (not a JRE)**, as the javadoc command is not included in JRE. Therefore `Use Internal JRE` does not work with maven attach-javadocs.

Answer (score 1):

Ensuring that my *IntelliJ -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Runner* settings indicated a **JDK** rather than only a JRE, as [helps some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48827066/545127), did not help me (for IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2 Community Edition on Ubuntu 20.04).

I found I also had to tell the *Maven Runner* to use a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable explicitly set to the JDK location.

Answer (score -1):

Adding [javadocExecutable property](http://mgorski.net/2013/dev/fail-to-execute-javadoc-plugin-on-mac-osx-java_home-issue) worked for me.

Comment: whats the -ve vote for? I am saying this worked for me. is this not recommended ?